# rbenv with hook

Tags: rbenv

I'm a totally new to ruby and rbenv, but I'm trying to get this 'bwoken' app working with rbenv.

This is bwoken, it's for iOS UIAutomation testing:
https://github.com/bendyworks/bwoken

My question is how do I add hooks for rbenv?

It says:

`Ensure your after_cd_bundler rvm hook is enabled:`

$ chmod u+x ~/.rvm/hooks/after_cd_bundler
Then, add the following line to your Rakefile:

Ok, so I see comments in the version history here
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

saying this:

`Added /usr/lib/rbenv/hooks to the plugin hook search path.`

`Added /usr/local/etc/rbenv.d to the list of directories searched for rbenv hooks.`

The problem is what is the original default place for adding the hook? They don't mention it anywhere.  Where is the correct place to put it?

Answer (score 0):

For rbenv you'd have to use a dot (.) file like .rbenv_version. The plugin talks configuration in a rvm context. Both are different ways of having multiple ruby version on the same system.